# ALL NaN values after accuracy is trained using K-cross validation

Tags: machine-learning, classification

```
    from keras.wrappers.scikit_learn import KerasClassifier
    from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
    def build_classifier():
        classifier = Sequential()
        classifier.add(Dense(units = 6, activation = 'relu', input_dim = 11, kernel_initializer = 
        'uniform'))
        classifier.add(Dense(units = 6, activation = 'relu', kernel_initializer = 'uniform'))
        classifier.add(Dense(units = 1, activation = 'sigmoid', kernel_initializer = 'uniform'))
        classifier.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'binary_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy'])
        return classifier

    classifier = KerasClassifier(build_fn = build_classifier, batch_size = 10, epochs = 100)
    accuracies = cross_val_score(estimator = classifier, X = X_train, y = y_train, cv = 10, n_jobs = -1)
```

/*This code seems pretty clean but the K_cross validation doesnt seem to work. It returns Nan and executes pretty fast as opposed to when using all the CPUs*/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is potentially an error with the classifier function that you have defined which is giving you a faulty output. My guess would be to check if you have defined the number of input nodes in the input layer appropriately since the rest of your code seems to be on point.